# Lob locator on new row in a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, blob

I'm trying to create a trigger which copies a blob from table `B` into the newly create row in table `A`. However, I get the error `ORA-22275` (Invalid lob locator specified) when the trigger is supposed to be executed. I can imagine the way I access the blob of the new row is not the right way, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Code of the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER COPY_BLOB
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_A
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  src blob;
BEGIN
     SELECT bytes INTO src FROM table_b WHERE id = :new.ref_id; 
     DBMS_LOB.COPY(:new.bytes, src, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src), 1, 1);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your trigger should just be:

```
SELECT bytes 
  INTO :new.bytes 
  FROM table_b 
 WHERE id = :new.ref_id;
```

no need to use the DBMS_LOB package at all.

Comment: Thank you, your statement works. Is there any difference speedwise? Is the `select` statement or `DMBS COPY` faster?

Comment: @Teinacher the select would be faster (oracle would copy the lob under the covers for you)